# Trying to analyze Gson project with sonarQube "Failed to execute goal biz.aQute.bnd:bnd-maven-plugin:6.2.0:bnd-process (default) on project gson"

Tags: sonarqube, gson

I have downloaded a .zip of the official Gson project repo from github.
I have docker installed And I'm trying to analyze Gson with SonarQube.

I have chose the `local project` option and created a new token and chose maven to analyze:

when I run this command:

```
mvn clean verify sonar:sonar -Dsonar.projectKey=GSON-res -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 -Dsonar.login=token_code
```

I get this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal biz.aQute.bnd:bnd-maven-plugin:6.2.0:bnd-process (default) on project gson: Classes found in the wrong directory: {com/google/gson/package-info.class=com\google\gson\package-info, com/google/gson/internal/package-info.class=com\google\gson\internal\package-info, com/google/gson/reflect/package-info.class=com\google\gson\reflect\package-info, com/google/gson/stream/package-info.class=com\google\gson\stream\package-info, com/google/gson/annotations/package-info.class=com\google\gson\annotations\package-info} -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be unrelated to SonarQube and is caused by a bug in the Maven Compiler Plugin version used by Gson: [MCOMPILER-485](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-485)

The Maven Compiler Plugin dependency of Gson has been updated to the fixed version 3.10.1, so this issue should be solved once you pull the latest Gson source code again.